# Why use -Lo- with curl when piping to bash?

Tags: bash, curl

In the janus project, they use curl to download and pipe a bootstrap script into bash.
https://github.com/carlhuda/janus

It looks like this:

```
$ curl -Lo- https://bit.ly/janus-bootstrap | bash
```

Why would one want to use the args `-Lo-`?

-o is supposed to be for output, but wouldn't that happen anyway (i.e. to stdout)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `-o` is redundant, they produce the exact same output:

```
$ curl --silent example.com | sha256sum
3587cb776ce0e4e8237f215800b7dffba0f25865cb84550e87ea8bbac838c423 *-

$ curl --silent --output - example.com | sha256sum
3587cb776ce0e4e8237f215800b7dffba0f25865cb84550e87ea8bbac838c423 *-
```

They have used that syntax since that line was [first introduced](http://github.com/carlhuda/janus/commit/8a93098#diff-04c6e90faac2675aa89e2176d2eec7d8R48) in 2011.
You might ask Wael Nasreddine ([@kalbasit](http://github.com/kalbasit) on GitHub) why he did it. He
is still active on that repo.

Comment: Yes that is redundant and probably coming from my lack of experience with Curl when I wrote that back in 2011 ref: https://github.com/carlhuda/janus/commit/8a93098005b7831049bba32a9cb0e5e86bdc53c3 This was addressed in https://github.com/carlhuda/janus/pull/639 Thanks Steven for the PR.

Comment: No worries! I'm not so experienced with Curl either, aside from the basics, so was trying to understand. Pretty cool to have a PR and merge already :)

Answer (score 13):

It's all in the [man pages](http://linux.die.net/man/1/curl):

[`-L`](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-L) in case the page has moved (3xx response) curl will redirect the request to the new address

[`-o`](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-o) output to a file instead of stdout (usually the screen). In your case the `o` flag is redundant since the output is piped to bash (for execution) - not to a file.